# Jenkins pipeline send email error "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm integrating Squish automation tool and Jenkins pipeline. Everything went smoothly. Now I need to send email report after the job's done. I have a Groovy file in pre-send script, but when this script runs, it throws out exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getRootDir() on null object

I figured out the "build" object in my Groovy script is Null. Not sure why it is. Please note if I use built-in Squish plugin and Editable Email on Jenkins, everything went smoothly. The problem just happen when I moved to use Pipeline.

@@@ - This is my Groovy script:

```
List getJenkinsTestResultFiles() {
    File squishResultsPath = new File( build.getRootDir(), "squishResults" )
    if ( !squishResultsPath.exists() || !squishResultsPath.isDirectory() ) {
       throw new GroovyRuntimeException( "Squish results path does not exist at: " + squishResultsPath.getAbsolutePath() )
    }


    File summaryFile = new File( squishResultsPath, "summary.xml" )
    if ( !summaryFile.exists() || !summaryFile.isFile() ) {
        throw new GroovyRuntimeException( "Squish summary file does not exist at: " + summaryFile.getAbsolutePath() )
    }

    List resultFiles = []
    def summaries = new XmlSlurper().parse( summaryFile )
    summaries.summary.each {
        resultFiles.push( new File( squishResultsPath, it.xmlFileName.text() ) )
    }

    return resultFiles
}
```

@@@ - This is my Pipeline script:

```
node('Slave_10.133.88.151') {

    stage('Squish Test') {
        step([$class: 'SquishBuilder',
            abortBuildOnError: false,
            extraOptions: '',
            host: '',
            port: '',
            resultFolder: "${WORKSPACE}\\Squish_Report",
            skipTestCases: false,
            snoozeFactor: '1',
            squishConfig: 'Default',
            testCase: '',
            testSuite: "${WORKSPACE}\\${TEST_SUITE}"])
    } 

    stage('Send Email') {
        emailext body: 'Test', 
        postsendScript: '${SCRIPT, template="SquishSummary.groovy"}', 
        subject: 'Pipeline', 
        to: 'hoang@local.com'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The build object is a hudson.model.Build object, and since you are calling a shared library you'll have to import the Build object in your groovy script.

```
import hudson.model.Build
```

At the top of your shared library.

If you have already imported the object then the issue could be that you haven't initialized it inside of your shared library.

Comment: Hi gavsyuk, thanks for your response. I figured out that the variable "build" in statement "build.getRootDir()" was invalid. We should change to "run.getRootDir()", this was already mentioned in Wiki page but I didn't see it.